# How to prototype a parallax-heavy interface

Tags: tools, prototype, parallax

I'd like to prototype a web site with a massive use of parallax effect, like this:

http://spider.mclarenautomotive.com/

For prototyping, I'd like to test how using this effect could influence the navigation and the user experience.

Do you have advice for prototyping it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [AxureRP](http://www.axure.com/) for that. A sample prototype is also available on their forum for that. http://www.axure.com/forum/tips-tricks-examples/8157-parallax-scrolling.html

> How to use this effect to better influence the navigation and the user
>   experience?

If you ask that does Parallax has an influence on user-experience then sure, everything you do in your website adds or subtracts from the user-experience but how can parallax be used to do that is too broad to answer. It depends on what is your context and what you are looking to achieve and then you may ask if Parallax can accomplish that.

Comment: nice! see the edits

Comment: I am impressed that Axure can now do that, but at the same time, it's not 'quite' as smooth as one would want/actually build it in code from the start. This is the catch22 of doing that level of fidelity in a tool like Axure. It 'looks real' but isn't quite. Sometimes that's no big deal, but sometimes that can lead to very misunderstood expectations.

Comment: Certain browsers perform better than other. Try to change the browser you publish for in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Build it. That level of animation would be as easy if not easier to build than dealing with prototyping software to emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think paper prototyping would be a good fit here.

Comment: Hi Max, could you expand a bit on why paper prototyping might be a good fit, particularly the parallax aspect? (sounds doable using layers but also sounds very fiddly)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Adobe Edge Animate with the Edge Commons library. The library includes a parallax effect.